# Why do I keep getting "not enough storage space"

Tags: applications, sd-card, storage, 6.0-marshmallow

I have an LG Stylo with a 32gb SD card, which is supported on my phone, and I have 29gb free. I try to move an app of any size and I am told there is not enough space. One or two apps move, but the majority won't. What is the point of walking someone through the steps and not allow it?
My system has been updated to 6.0 Marshmallow, but I was having the same issue before.
The Stylo has been great but I am starting to run low on space, which could be fixed using the SD card.

Comment: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526)

Answer (score 0):

Your phone has 8GB internal memory this is low if you have many apps installed, including updated apps.

1. If you turn on automatic update in google play, turn it off.
2. If it was already updated some Microsoft apps, uninstall them. This will return some space.
3. Facebook app is the big app. You can use Facebook lite or browsers instead.
4. Clear cache. Setting -> Storage/Usage -> click on cache and clear cache.
5. If you have Line or other chat apps, delete chat history one by one.

Hope this help.